# Gitlab CI/CD How to use PAT

Tags: gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to build my first pipeline. The goal is to download the git repo to a server. In doing so, I ran into the problem that I have 2FA enabled on my account. When I run the pipeline I get the following error message:

> remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password.

Pipeline:

```
download_repo:
  script:
    echo "Hallo"
```

As far as I understand I have to use a PAT because I have 2FA enabled. But unfortunately I have not found any info on how to use the PAT.

Answer (score 0):

To access one of your GitLab repository from your pipeline, you should [create a deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#git-clone-a-repository) (as described in [token overview](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/token_overview.html#deploy-tokens)).

As [noted here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/usage-of-deploy-tokens/70259/2):

> You get Deploy token username and password when you create deploy token on the repository you want to clone.
>
> You can also use Job token. Job token inherits permissions of the user triggering the pipeline.
> If your users have access to the repository you need to clone you can use `git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>`.
> More details on [Job token is here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html).

---

The [OP Assassinee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10830237/assassinee) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098933/gitlab-ci-cd-how-to-use-pat/75103570#comment132703272_75103570):

> The problem was that the agent could not access the repository.
>
> I added the following item in the agent configuration:
>
> ```
> clone_url = "https://<USER>:<PAT>@gitlab.example.com"
> ```
>
> This makes it possible for the agent to access the repository.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

I still haven't managed to do it with that though.

In my understanding, a new Docker container is created as soon as the pipeline is executed. In the container, the repository is then downloaded first and then the commands from the pipeline configuration are executed. So e.g. test is started or the project is created with make. Looking at the error message I think the problem is with the first step. It is not possible to access the repository.

My question would be, how can I tell the pipeline to use this deploy token?

Comment: @Assassinee The token should be available as a predefined environment variable, as [illustrated here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#gitlab-deploy-token).

Comment: I have done it now. The problem was that the agent could not access the repository. I added the following item in the agent configuration: 
clone_url = "https://<USER>:<PAT>@gitlab.example.com"
This makes it possible for the agent to access the repository.